# how to compare 2 rows in a dataGridView and highlight the different cells?

Tags: c#, datagridview

how to compare two selected rows in a dataGridView?
1.- I need to know how to detect the two selected rows
2.- Compare the two selected rows
3.- highlight the differences "cells"

I've tried this but unfortunately I am lost.....

```
DataTable src1 = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable; //THIS IS PROBABLY NOT NEEDED
    DataTable src2 = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
        int index1 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < src1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var row1 = src1.Rows[i].ItemArray;
            var row2 = src2.Rows[i].ItemArray;

            for (int j = 0; j < row1.Length; j++)
            {
                if (!row1[j].ToString().Equals(row2[j].ToString()))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code compares rows to itself which is never going to be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your code is not good i will answer your questions :

1.- I need to know how to detect the two selected rows

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows
```

2.- Compare the two selected rows it should look to something similar to follow :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count-1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
    {
        if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.rows[i].Cells[j].value.Equals(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.rows[i+1].Cells[j].value))
        {
            dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Rows[i+1].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }    
}
```

3.- highlight the differences "cells"

```
  dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
  dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Rows[i+1].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: thank you so much.... I was going in circles here. I just corrected some minor lowercase to uppercase corrections and it works! It is only highlighting the second selected row though... ho w can I get it to highlight the first selected row as well?

Comment: Sorry you should use i+1 in the second line :



dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
  dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Rows[i+1].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;