# Highlight differences between strings on winform

Tags: c#, string, winforms, datagridview, comparison

I am hoping somebody can help me out here and that this questions won't be too vague.

I am trying to determine a way that I can highlight the differences between two text strings within a winform.

I have the original string in one column of a data grid and the string to compare to in a second column.  What I would like is to highlight where the comparison string is different within the data grid view itself.

Example:

`Thanks for the hep`

`Thanks for the help!!`

where the `l`, and two `!` would be highlighted

I have tried the following (Shout out to Bouam for his help in this [Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722360/how-to-compare-2-rows-in-a-datagridview-and-highlight-the-different-cells)):

```
for (int i = 0; i < TextProcessingResults.RowCount; i++)
{
    if (TextProcessingResults.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null)
    {
        if ((string)TextProcessingResults.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != (string)TextProcessingResults.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value)
        {
            TextProcessingResults.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

But this only highlights which rows are different not at the character level. I'm new to all of this, so is this a crazy endeavor to undertake?

Could anybody help or point me towards a resource that would be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new `DatGridViewColumn` based on `RichTextBox` and then use your new rich text column, to highlight differences in rich text.

This may help you:

- [RichTextBox Cell in a DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView)

And here is an ouptput based on this:

[image]

You can apply the algorithm you need to compare strings for differences to columns and using this `DataGridViewRichTextBoxColumn` highlight the differences.

To learn more about creating custom datagridview column types you can take a look at [Build a Custom NumericUpDown Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Ah Reza...this is great!!  A bit overwhelming at the moment for my skill level, but I am certainly up for the challenge.  I will try this and post back with the results.

Comment: @IrishMickeyWard When you find an answer helpful you can kindly accept it by click on check mark at left side of answer, this way, it will be more useful for future readers.

Comment: Yes Reza! This gives me what I need. Sorry for the delay in updating.

Comment: @IrishMickeyWard Happy to hear that it was helpful:) you are welcome.