# How to compare two cell values in separate columns and highlight the difference in a DataGridView

Tags: c#

I was looking up this question and saw it was asked for comparing row values but I didn't see one asking about column values which is what I'm trying to do.

An example of some data i would be getting in this dataGridView would be something like this below

```
    2 2 2 2
    1 1 1 1
    1 2 1 1 
    2 2 2 1
    1 2 2 2
```

And I would want the last three rows to be highlighted as having differences because not all numbers in those columns match. If there's a way to highlight the specific number that doesn't match that's even better.

Would this be done the same way as comparing row values? If not how could I do this task?

The post I mentioned about the row comparison question can be found at [how to compare 2 rows in a dataGridView and highlight the different cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27722360/10022695)

Comment: The question needs clarification.  It seems like you're asking multiple questions. Do you need help with making the GUI elements display what you want?  Or do you need help with algorithm detection of duplicate values?

Comment: Also, I see you did some research, but it might be helpful if you could clarify exactly what you've tried and what isn't working for you.

Comment: @JamesHoux I need help with the detection. I tried using dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Rows from the linked example answer but instead replaced both Rows with Columns but my code does not recognize the .Columns. I tried using the same code just to see what would happen but it didn't recognize the .Rows in that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below method should highlight each **row** where values are not uniform.

```
    public void HighlightNonUniformRows()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in excelView_DGV.Rows)
        {
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White; // set to default until non-uniform value is detected
            for (int i = 0; i < r.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                int j = i + 1;
                if (!r.Cells[i].Value.Equals(r.Cells[j].Value))
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; // or other desired highlight color
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You also mentioned "highlighting the specific number that does not match". Assuming that a maximum of one number is different from the others in a given row (as in your example data), this can be done using the modified method below.

```
    public void HighlightNonUniformRowCells()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in excelView_DGV.Rows)
        {
            r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White; // set to default until non-uniform value is detected
            for (int i = 0; i < r.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                int j = i + 1;
                if (!r.Cells[i].Value.Equals(r.Cells[j].Value))
                {
                    if (i == 0 && r.Cells[j].Equals(r.Cells[j + 1])) r.Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Red; // edge case - first cell contains the non-uniform value
                    else r.Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for what I wanted to do. Out of curiosity what would you do if there were multiple different values in a row? Say there was a row of 1 2 2 1 and if were basing it off of the first value in the row how would you mark the 2's?

Comment: You could use a variable to track the first value in the row (ie `int val = (int)r.Cells[0].Value` ), then use code similar to that of the `HighlightNonUniformRowCells()` method to highlight each cell that does not match that value (iterate over each cell - set `r.Cells[j].Style.BackColor` property to desired highlight color for each cell that does not contain the same value as the first).